# How to redirect old url to new url while migrating to new site in react and django?

Tags: reactjs, django

I have an old website and new website built with React and django. I'm in the process of migrating from the old site to the new one and need to implement SEO-friendly URL redirects. There are more that 500 old url that needs to be redirected to new ones.

I came to know about redirect apps in django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/redirects/) but dont get how to achieve it on the frontend.

I'm not sure how to properly set up SEO-friendly URL redirects from my old url to the new ones while preserving SEO attributes.

If I add all those urls in react and call an API to find where i have to redirect will it affect seo? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of redirect:

301 - permanent redirect
302 - temporary redirect

If you use a 301, search engines are supposed to transfer all the SEO from the old link to the new link. Having spoken to a number of SEO people over the years, I'm not entirely clear whether this always happens or not in all situations. Regardless, it's the best way of maintaining as much of your SEO advantages as you already have on the "old" link.

One caveat is do NOT use a 301 if the redirect is not going to be permanent - that will mess up your SEO.

As for Django, not sure what the problem is - use the `redirects` app, as you already mention. Add the old links and point them to the new ones.

> dont get how to achieve it on the frontend.

Your new frontend should already have the new links. There's nothing else to "achieve" here - you set the redirects to point to these.

Edit: After clarification of the problem in a comment - that this is about redirecting to an entirely new domain (Not clear in original question) ...

In this instance, you should configure whatever you are using to serve your applications (nginx, apache) to handle this, it would be far simpler.

Example of rerouting requests using nginx

```
server{
...
    location /my_url {
        rewrite ^/my_url(.*)$ https://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 permanent;
    }
...
}
```

If all your urls are basically the same, just on a new domain, you could redirect the whole lot in one go:

```
return 301 $scheme://www.mynewdomain.com$request_uri;
```

Exact solution here depends on what server you're using, how your new routes compare to your old ones etc. I suggest you read up on the docs for whatever server you are using to find the best solution.

Comment: my frontend is on different domain so if I hit `example.com/old-url/` I will go to `404` or I could use `<Redirect from="/old-path" to="/new-path" />` (In this case there is no meaning of using redirects app in django) but will it be same as `301` ?

Comment: Edited for new info ...